# Can I use a group switch to bypass a PV inverter?

Tags: power, switches, inverter, solar-energy

I have an PV inverter which takes power input from

- the main grid and
- the PV modules/battery

Depending on availability, the power output to my house will be a mix of these inputs. In a usecase I want to be able to bypass the inverter completely, so my house is powered by the main grid directly and solely. Here's a schematics I am thinking of, would that work? What must be considered?

[image]

So the switch `S1` has two connected inputs. In case one, (A path) only the main grid will be directed to my house. In case two (B path), inverter will be used to determine how much of the power mix will be directed to my house. This is the switch I want to use: [SFT232](https://www.hager.at/produktkatalog/energieverteilung-und-schutz-schaltgeraete/reiheneinbaugeraete/schalter-taster-meldegeraete/schalter/sft232/221264.htm). My house has only a single phase.

The reason I want to do this, is so that I can cut off the main grid input to the inverter conveniently. I don't want to worry about whether it is consuming energy from the main grid when I am charging my EV, for example.

Comment: Is this the actual wiring of your solar panel system? I'd expect that the inverter has only one connection to the grid, not two.

Comment: It is only one connection from inverter to main grid.